# How do I check if something was already chosen?

Tags: python

I have a question, so I want to make an app that gives you a random name from an array after inserting your name, something like this:

Type your name: Nico
Name chosen for you is: John

So I made an array with some names, but I want to check if a name was already chosen for someone and if was then remove it from an array or just make it unable to roll from an array.
Do u know what I mean?
I don't want a situation when name from an array will be printed twice for two different typed names.

How to do it? I'm writing in python3

Answer (score 1):

You can [`remove`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists) that name from your list:

```
aliases = ['John', 'Bob', 'Frank']
aliases.remove('John')
print(aliases) # ['Bob', 'Frank']
```

This is assuming you don't have duplicates in your list (in which case only the first matching element will be removed)

Answer (score 0):

You can do as follows using [random.choice()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html) and list [remove()](https://docs.python.org/3.6/tutorial/datastructures.html) methods:

```
import random

names = ["Fred", "Marcy", "john"]
name = random.choice(names)
names.remove(name)
```